# Python import returns ModuleNotFoundError when importing from my own file

Tags: python, import, pyqt

I have a really simple situation: I'm working on a project with python and PyQt6, and I want my custom widget and window classes to be in separate files. Right now I have 2 files, 1 for custom widgets, 1 for custom windows. I want to import my custom widget class to the file that contains the windows related classes, but it fails with ModuleNotFoundError.

For reference:

CustomWidgets.py

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSpinBox, QDoubleSpinBox, QSlider

class SliderSpinBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SliderSpinBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.spinbox = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.trackbar = QSlider()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.trackbar)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

MainWindow.py

```
#PyQt6 imports
...
from CustomWidgets import SliderSpinBox

#classes
...
```

Error: *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'CustomWidgets'*
Do you have any ideas what is wrong with what I do?

I tried making different files for the different windows classes. When I tried to import 1 class from another file, the same happened. Imports work with the PyQt6 and opencv libraries just fine.

Comment: You haven't specified the directory structure, or how you launch your project. I suspect the files aren't in the working directory, and/or you haven't specified any PYTHONPATH to where they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it depends on how you have structured your project. And second try to specify the absolute path of the imports starting from your working directory.

Example, considering the project structure:

```
YourWorkingDir/
│
├── MainPackage/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   │
│   ├── CustomWidgetsPackage/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── slider_spinbox.py
│   │   └── some_other_custom_widget.py
│   │
│   └── MyWindows/
│      ├── __init__.py
│      ├── main_window.py
│      └── some_other_window.py
│
│
└── main.py
```

defining your `SliderSpinBox` widget in `slider_spinbox.py`

```
# /YourWorkingDir/MainPackage/CustomWidgetsPackage/slider_spinbox.py

from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QLabel, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QSpinBox, QDoubleSpinBox, QSlider

class SliderSpinBox(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SliderSpinBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.spinbox = QDoubleSpinBox()
        self.trackbar = QSlider()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.spinbox)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.trackbar)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
```

the `main_window.py` should be:

```
# /YourWorkingDir/MainPackage/MyWindows/main_window.py

# PyQt6 imports
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

from MainPackage.CustomWidgetsPackage.slider_spinbox import SliderSpinBox

# classes
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    ...
```

and then in your `main.py` file:

```
# PyQt6 imports
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication

from MainPackage.MyWindows.main_window import MainWindow

# other imports
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

the same should apply to deeper nested packages and modules.

Aside:

we could also use relative imports: in the `__init__.py` of the `CustomWidgetsPackage` we could specify:

```
from .. CustomWidgets.slider_spinbox import SliderSpinBox
# each dot represent a level starting from the root directory
```

and on the `main_window.py` file we could import `SliderSpinBox` as:

```
from MainPackage.CustomWidgetsPackage import SliderSpinBox
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The problem was that I didn't specify the package I wanted to import the .py files. So instead of `from CustomWidgets import SliderSpinBox` I needed to use `from GUI.CustomWidgets import SliderSpinBox`, because that was the directory my custom widgets were. It didn't matter that my Window.py was in the same directory, the package was needed to be specified.